# FreeBSD: How do I install port which doesn't show in searches?

Tags: freebsd, freenas, bsd-ports

I'd like to install version 6 of unifi network controller in a jail on my FreeNAS server.  I can see that a `net-mgmt/unifi6` port exists in bugs.freebsd.org: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249466.  However I can't find it by searching any of the following places:

- `/usr/ports` directory
- `pkg search` command
- https://www.freebsd.org/ports/searching.html web page

I'm guessing this is in a pre-release state.  Is it possible to install?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to obtain the files from bugzilla and make the port manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see on bugs is conversation regarding updating to unifi6. It's not available in ports right now but, since the PR was only filed six days ago, it looks like someone is very, very close to completing it.

In the meantime, it's not available anywhere from FreeBSD itself. The best you could do right now is try to install it yourself from the unifi site but that would probably take longer than just waiting for the FreeBSD maintainer.

You can also contact the maintainer to see what his progress is on it.